# Select rows from a vector and find the associated file in folder in R

Tags: r, vector

I have a result vector of 400 rows with 2 columns. This vector is obtained after the analysis of 400 images stored into a folder. Images are named 1 to 400. The first column of the vector is the image number (from 1 to 400). The second column is the analysis results, in this case it can have 4 states: a, b, c, d. I would like to modify all the images that have a specific state (by example all the image with state b).

How to select rows from this vector based on the values of the state (2nd column)? Then how to find the associated image in the folder?

Comment: Please add a reproducible example and show the expected output based on that. Read  [here how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to filter your image names based on the result of the analysis. Two options:

```
df <- data.frame(
  image_nr = 1:400,
  analysis_result = rep(c("a", "b", "c", "d"),100)
)

# Find all images with state b
images1 <- df$image_nr[which(df$analysis_result == "b")]
print(images1)

# or use dplyr
df %>%
  dplyr::filter(analysis_result == "b")
```

Subsequently, you can use the image names to find the files in your folder using something like `paste0(images1, ".png")` and `list.files()`.
(e.g. https://www.masterdataanalysis.com/r/working-with-files-and-folders-in-r/)

Comment: # Find all images with state b
images1 <- df$image_nr[which(df$analysis_result == "b")]
list <- paste0(images1, ".jpg")

# I choose the working folder where I have my image
folder <- setwd("C:/Users/PC/Desktop/New folder/")

# I do not see how to use choose list from list.files function
jpeg <- list.files(folder, pattern = list)

Comment: Can you be more explicit about what you mean with "Then how to find the associated image in the folder?". Do you want to somehow open the images and R for analysis or something?

Comment: From the vector the image name can be filtered and can be stored into 
a list ###> list <- paste0(images1, ".jpg")
> list
[1] "2.jpg"  "4.jpg"  "6.jpg"  "8.jpg"  "10.jpg"
It is just the name of the image. From the folder I would like to select these images, store using #### jpeg <- list.files(folder, pattern = list) #### and perform an analysis. In my case change the color.

Comment: Once you have the image names in a vector, you can easily select them from your folder.  You can for example use the package rimager for image analysis in R. The tutorial shows how you can import images into R: https://dahtah.github.io/imager/imager.html